# Save state of TextInput array - React Native

Tags: react-native, save, state, render, textinput

I am fetching from API multiple TextInputs and displaying them on my screen. So, how can I save the state of user inputs to a global object. Something like this:

```
    state = {
    foundtextfields: []
   }
```

**Here I am pushing those fetched TextInputs to foundTextFields[] array:**

```
var foundTextFields = [];

    foundTextFields.push(<TextInput>{keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i].placeholderText}</TextInput>)
```

**And I am displaying text inputs in this list:**

```
return (
    <View>
      {foundtextfields}
    </View>
)
```

**EDIT:**
I want to loop through the state of the array, and extract the key from that ex. “key” (signedbyFullName) and match if that is the same with the json body property "signedbyFullName" like below.

```
  postToBmp = (obje) => {
var userArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < this.myInputFields.myTextFields.length; i++) {
       userArray.push(this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i])
       console.log("this is the title of al inputFields:",   this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].key)
}

fetch('URL', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
  },
  credentials: 'include',

  body: JSON.stringify({

    from: 'test1@test.dk',

    to: ['<test@hotmail.com>'],

    signedByFullName: '',

    signedByCPRNumber: '',

    otherCompanyName: '',

    otherCompanyCVRNumber: ''
  })
})
```

}

Comment: What is the problem can you display the `TextInputs` or just need help to store the values?

Comment: @MPN7 I just need help to store the values. In fact I tried this to store values: this.state.foundtextfields.push(…) and call in view {this.state.foundtextfields}. It works this way but I am using a Modal and whenever I toggle it, textinputs duplicates. I dont know why!

Comment: Where are you doing this `this.state.foundtextfields.push(…)`? if you are doing it in the Modal it self it's normal that it duplicates

Comment: @MPN7 Nono modal is inside another function's return View. Still, it doesnt make sense why is it doing it. It seems like everytime I toggle Modal, it refreshes the page, thus my fetch() calls data again + data that are already saved in state, therefor they are so many displaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store the values you can create an array along side `foundtextfields` with the values, and every time you change a text you set it to the index of the other array
Like so:

```
    foundTextFields.push(
      <TextInput 
         onChangeText={(text) =>{
            let inputValues=this.state.inputValues;
            inputValues[i]=text;
            this.setState({inputValues})
         }}>
        {keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i].placeholderText}
      </TextInput>)
```

**OR**

```
foundTextFields.push(
      <TextInput 
         onChangeText={(text) =>{
            keyvalue_to_json=this.state.keyvalue_to_json
            keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i].inputValues=text;
            this.setState({keyvalue_to_json})
         }}>
        {keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i].placeholderText}
      </TextInput>)
```

Comment: If I want to loop through that array in the State, how can I identify to which TextInput does each value belongs to?

Comment: Cicle through your API array `keyvalue_to_json.inputFields`, the values of input are in the same index as that array. If that confuses you, see edit i set the input values to the `keyvalue_to_json.inputFields` so it has all values

Comment: Because you are not initializing inputFields anywhere, and you are not setting state.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood. I want to loop through state of that array, from another function. I have a function called postToApi() and there I want to loop through the state. Check Edited question.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood but let me explain: The second way uses the variable of your array json that came from your api call. From the code you provided I believe you are doing an loop and for each element of `keyvalue_to_json.inputFields`  you create a new inputBox, so instead of creating a new variable I set the values of the inputs to the original, api variable (`keyvalue_to_json.inputFields`), I don't set state 'cus I thought that `keyvalue_to_json.inputFields` wasn't on state since you were having problems with state.

Comment: The first approach that you gave it worked perfectly, it saves on state. But I need everything to be saved on state. Each TextInput that I am fetching from API is an object, and each contains some key with values, around 4. So I want all of them to be saved in state, including the user input value.

Comment: Can you please just tell me how to save state of all TextInputs + user inputs? Your second approach doesnt work, state prints an empty array, so it is not saving anything there.

Comment: did you see my edit? I already added code that saves into state

Comment: Can you rename them, you have used keyvalues_to_json in a strange way. That code throws an error. Check the previous one that you did and make the changes on syntax.

Comment: @MPN7 i tried that code but it seems its something wrong with it.